# VB.Net DropDown List Value being set to 0

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a search of a database that is called in one of two ways,

the first is a postback event, from a search field \ text box and button click event, the other is from the query string. Both call the same method and both pass the resulting datatable onto a method that should populate dropdowns and textboxes with the values that come back.

The problem that I have is when I search using the query string like as below

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack And Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("CaseId")) Then
        GetCaseInfo(Request.QueryString("CaseId"), True)
End If
```

the code that I use to get the caseId on the button is

```
Protected Sub SearchCase(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bttnSearchCase.Click

    GetCaseInfo(txtCaseSearchId.Text, True)

End Sub
```

I get to line `If Not dt(0)("AmendmentsToAccount") Is DBNull.Value Then ddlAmendmentsOnAccount.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt16(dt(0)("AmendmentsToAccount")) Else ddlAmendmentsOnAccount.SelectedIndex = 0` and then all the `SelectedIndex`es of the drop-down lists return 0 except `ddlReason`.

However, when searching with a textbox and clicking the button that comes into the same method all the correct values stay.

the code that is changing the selected indexes is

```
If Not dt(0)("EvidenceCaseCorrect") Is DBNull.Value Then ddlEvidenceCorrect.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt16(dt(0)("EvidenceCaseCorrect")) Else ddlEvidenceCorrect.SelectedIndex = 0
    If Not dt(0)("ApplicationOnFile") Is DBNull.Value Then ddlApplicationOnFile.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt16(dt(0)("ApplicationOnFile")) Else ddlApplicationOnFile.SelectedIndex = 0
    If Not dt(0)("RemediationRequired") Is DBNull.Value Then ddlRemediationRequired.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt16(dt(0)("RemediationRequired")) Else ddlRemediationRequired.SelectedIndex = 0
    If Not dt(0)("Reason") Is DBNull.Value Then ddlListReason.SelectedValue = Convert.ToInt16(dt(0)("Reason")) Else ddlListReason.SelectedValue = 0
    If Not dt(0)("ScoredCorrectly") Is DBNull.Value Then ddlScoreCorrectly.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt16(dt(0)("ScoredCorrectly")) Else ddlScoreCorrectly.SelectedIndex = -0
    If Not dt(0)("TransmittedCorrectly") Is DBNull.Value Then ddlTransmittedCorrectly.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt16(dt(0)("TransmittedCorrectly")) Else ddlTransmittedCorrectly.SelectedIndex = 0
    If Not dt(0)("ArrearsFlagPresent") Is DBNull.Value Then ddlAreas.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt16(dt(0)("ArrearsFlagPresent")) Else ddlAreas.SelectedIndex = 0
    txtRetirementAge.Text = dt(0)("RetirementAge").ToString()
    If Not dt(0)(10) Is DBNull.Value Then ddlBreach.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt16(dt(0)("Breach")) Else ddlBreach.SelectedIndex = 0
    txtOriginalAdvice.Text = dt(0)("OriginalAdvance").ToString()
    txtCompletionDate.Text = dt(0)("CompletionDate").ToString()
    txtInterestRate.Text = dt(0)("InterestRate").ToString()
    txtDateAppliedTo.Text = dt(0)("DatesAppliedFrom").ToString()   'change name on field and a new field here
    txtDateAppliedFrom.Text = dt(0)("DatesAppliedTo").ToString()   'change name on field and a new field here
    txtCorrectTerm.Text = dt(0)("CorrectTerm").ToString()
    txtTermCompletion.Text = dt(0)("TermAtCompletion").ToString()
    txtRemainignTerm.Text = dt(0)("RemainingTerm").ToString()
    txtDiffInTerm.Text = dt(0)("DifferenceInTerm").ToString()
    If Not dt(0)("AmendmentsToAccount") Is DBNull.Value Then ddlAmendmentsOnAccount.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt16(dt(0)("AmendmentsToAccount")) Else ddlAmendmentsOnAccount.SelectedIndex = 0
```

The reason the selected index values are converted to in16 variables is that when it comes in because its recorded as a number its being seen as a Boolean value not an integer value.

The question I have is why on the line mentioned above does it reset all the dropdown selected index values back to 0 on all but one?

Comment: Because it is setting `ddlListReason.SelectedValue = 0` not the `SelectedIndex`?

Comment: I did notice that and tried changing it, but that doesn't explain why all the other values are resetting to 0. when they get to that bottom line